# Remote connection to XFCE desktop from windows OS : ALT+Tab is cycling through the windows OS apps. How can we restrict it to per OS

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Suppose I have 20 apps open in my Windows OS - Firefox, Chrome, VNC launcher, XLS, PPT, etc.

And now I have connected to a machine using VNC that has XFCE deskeop viewer.

I want to have a control so that if I am in XFCE terminal/windows and do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it should cycle among *remote machine* windows/open apps and vice-versa.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, the answer to your question lies in how to configure the Windows side (more specifically the VNC viewer you are using) to not interpret these keyboard shortcuts and send them to the remote side instead. As such, it is off-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is the configuration of the Windows-side VNC client. As such, it should be asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) instead of here.